# PHP code in <script> tag make function javascript in bellow code not defined

Tags: javascript, php

I make a form that has a table with dynamic row. each column in row will has select option input that get from php. when i click a button to add new row.
I use json_encode to transform array of key-value php to javascript json. Bellow that I have tried. Anyone can explain me? thanx

```
 <!--  triger add row -->
  <button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>

</body>


<!-- javascript -->

1. 
<script>
  let options = <?php echo json_encode($options)?>
</script>
<script>

  function addRow(){

     //this will produce Reference error : options is not defined

     options.forEach(createOptionElement(option))
  }
</script>

2. 
<script>
  let options = <?php echo json_encode($options)?>

 // function addRow will be Reference error : addRow is not defined

  function addRow(){
     options.forEach(createSelectElement(option))
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Go with option 2 and also add an event listener after the function declaration instead of using the `onclick` attribute (using those attributes is discouraged anyway)

Comment: You would provide a [mcve]. If you have a JavaScript problem then show the JavaScript and not the PHP that generates it. Don't omit vital information like the `createOptionElement` (which doesn't need to be your real `createOptionElement` function, you can simplify it, just so long as the problem you are asking about is demonstrated).

Comment: ok Quentin thanx for suggestion, I will asked with better example and clear